# Python matrix multiplication index exchange memory usage example

Tags: python, c, numpy, matrix

in c there is an example of importance of memory utilization: naive matrix multiplication using 3 for loops (i,j,k). And one can show that using (i,k,j) is much faster than (i,j,k) due to memory coalescence. In python numpy the order if indexes (again naive 3 loops, not np.dot) does not matter. Why is that?

Comment: Isn't the native `c` multidimensional array an array of pointers to further arrays?  Sort of like the Python nested list?  `numpy` arrays use a flat databuffer, and implement multidimensionality with shape and strides.  That use of strides greatly reduces the dependence on index order.

Comment: Clarify something for me - how are you using/controlling the order of indices in `numpy`?  You aren't talking about Python level iterations, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to know why the loop `(i,k,j)` is faster than  `(i,j,k)` on C. That's happens because the memory usage optimization, in your computer memory the matrix is allocated in a linear way, so if you iterate using  `(i,k,j)` you are using this in your favor where each loop takes a block of memory and load to your RAM. If you use `(i,j,k)` you are working against it, and each step will take a block of memory load to your RAM and discard on next step because you are iterating jumping blocks.

The implementation of `numpy` handle it for you, so even if you use the worst order `numpy` will order it to work faster.

The event of throwing away the cache, and keep changing it all the time is called [Cache miss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#frb-inline)

At [this link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/) you can see a much better explanation about how the memory is allocated and why is it faster in some specific itartion way.